# Unexpected .htaccess behaviour

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Having issues with .htaccess file - all I'm wanting to do is remove .php extensions, which is usually no problem. I'm specifically wanting to only rewrite URLs containing alpha characters only (hence the capture group).

Rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)?$ /$1.php

</IfModule>
```

The rule works only on URLs that should return a 404 - ie, if I request mydomain.com/somegarbagestring, I get a 404, mydomain.com/somegarbagestring.php was not found on this server. The 404 is expected, and the requested domain includes the .php extension, as it should

If I request a genuine URL - ie mydomain.com/thisisarealpage, the requested page does not include the .php extension.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0):

And.... as soon as I posted the question, found my solution:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```